# SELECT query that Selects from Next Row given certain criteria using SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a table that shows employees' hire and accompanying term date on the same line. I'm using data in 2 tables: `employees` and `EEChange`.

`EEChange` has three columns that are important: `employee_no`, `action_date`, `action_type`. The `action_type` will only be 'H', 'R' or 'T' for 'Hire', 'Rehire' or 'Term'. As far as I'm concerned the 'Hire' and 'Rehire' dates are effective dates and the 'Term' dates are termination dates.

I can create a select query that places the effective dates (ED) in the ED column and the term dates (TD) in the TD column. The problem is they are not on the same row. Another difficulty I'm having is that there may not be an associated TD for every ED. See below: Employee (EE) 14 was Hired on 5/1/98, rehired on 9/13/06 and termed on 3/23/98. I do not know why my database has a Rehire followed by a Hire. A far as I am concerned EE 14 was hired on 5/1/98 and termed on 3/23/98. I am going to assume there was no break in employment.

Here are my tables:

`employees`:

```
EE No   Name
6       Anil
12      Viktor
14      Sherry
15      Juan
48      Susan
50      Kevin
```

`EEChange`:

```
EE No   Action_type Action_date
6       H           5/1/1998
6       T           7/26/2010
12      H           5/1/1998
12      R           4/16/2012
14      H           5/1/1998
14      R           9/13/2006
14      T           9/19/2008
15      H           3/23/1998
48      H           7/1/1998
48      R           10/21/2008
48      T           1/3/2009
50      H           7/2/1998
50      R           7/16/2010
50      T           5/1/2012
50      R           12/1/2013
50      T           2/15/2015
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    LTRIM(employees.employee_no) as [EE No],
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY employees.employee_no ORDER BY EEChange.action_date) AS [Seq],
    EEChange.action_type,
    CASE 
       WHEN EEChange.action_type = 'H' OR EEChange.action_type = 'R' 
         THEN EEChange.action_date
    END AS [Effective Date],
    CASE 
       WHEN EEChange.action_type = 'T' 
         THEN EEChange.action_date
    END AS [Term Date]
FROM 
    dbo.employees employees
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.emp_employment_action_changes EEchange ON employees.employee_no = EEChange.employee_no
```

I added the `Sequence` column to see if I could order the `action_date` column per `[EE No]`. I was able to do so, but ultimately unsuccessful and finding a select query that would give me the desired result: ED and TD on the same line.

My result:

```
EE No   Seq action_type Effective Date  Term Date
6       1   H           5/1/1998    
6       2   T                           7/26/2010
12      1   H           5/1/1998    
12      2   R           4/16/2012   
14      1   H           5/1/1998    
14      2   R           9/13/2006   
14      3   T                           9/19/2008
15      1   H           3/23/1998   
48      1   H           7/1/1998
48      2   R           10/21/2008  
48      3   T                           1/3/2009
50      1   H           7/2/1998
50      2   R           7/16/2010
50      3   T                           5/1/2012
50      4   R           12/1/2013
50      5   T                           2/15/2015
```

**Desired result**:

```
EE No   Name    Effective Date  Term Date
6       Anil    5/1/1998        7/26/2010
12      Viktor  5/1/1998    
14      Sherry  5/1/1998        9/19/2008
15      Juan    3/23/1998   
48      Susan   7/1/1998        1/3/2009
50      Kevin   7/2/1998        5/1/2012
50      Kevin   12/1/2013       2/15/2015
```

Notice how Kevin has 5 lines in the `EEChange` table. I only want the first ED its accompanying Term date and the next ED and accompanying Term date. For active EEs there will be no final term date.

Any help anyone can give would be great. I tried using `LEAD()` but it doesn't work with SQL Server 2008 R2. I couldn't find a way to make `LEAD()` skip over EDs that came in the sequence before TDs.

Comment: `LAG` and `LEAD` are **new features** in SQL Server **2012**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like your problem really is a gaps-and-island problem, meaning that you need to find the start and end of discrete ranges. If we treat both actions H and R as markers for the start of a range the problem will be to find the earliest end date succeeding every start date that is later than the date. (Sort of - I find it hard to describe). The logic should be pretty easy to follow though.

I tested with your sample data and this query seems to give the desired result.

```
with 
a as (
    select 
       e.EENo, e.Name, 
       case 
          when Action_type IN ('R','H') 
          then Action_date 
       end Effective_date, 
       case 
          when Action_type = 'T' 
          then Action_date 
       end Term_date
    from employees e 
    join EEChange ee on e.EENo = ee.EENo
), 
b as (
    select 
       EENo, Name, Effective_date, 
       case 
          when Effective_date is not null 
          then (
             select min(term_date) 
             from a a2  
             where a2.Term_date > a.Effective_date and a2.EENo = a.EENo
             ) 
       end Term_date
    from a
)
select 
    EENo, Name, min(Effective_date) Effective_date, Term_date 
from b 
where Effective_date is not null
group by EENo, Name, Term_date
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2fa2/1)

Sample result:

```
| EENo |   Name | Effective_date |  Term_date |
|------|--------|----------------|------------|
|    6 |   Anil |     1998-05-01 | 2010-07-26 |
|   12 | Viktor |     1998-05-01 |     (null) |
|   14 | Sherry |     1998-05-01 | 2008-09-19 |
|   15 |   Juan |     1998-03-23 |     (null) |
|   48 |  Susan |     1998-07-01 | 2009-01-03 |
|   50 |  Kevin |     1998-07-02 | 2012-05-01 |
|   50 |  Kevin |     2013-12-01 | 2015-02-15 |
```

Comment: but the above query is not showing result for 50 kevin term_date is null

Comment: @mohan111 What? Kevin has been terminated two times and that's exactly what shows up. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: sorry i have note it down wrong data in my source code

Comment: i have written code  for this but because of wrong data in my declared tables giving me null values for kevin record now i have taken your table data and it is working fine

Comment: @mohan111 I think there might be flaw in your code as it won't pick up on several discrete ranges as you rely on `seq > 3` in your second union. See this fiddle where I inserted some extra data for Kevin and notice the difference in output between our queries: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45080/1

Comment: yeah i agree with your opinion but as per limited data provided by OP i have written code like this.I will work it out on that

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @employees  table  (EE int, Name varchar(20));
insert @employees values 
(6,'Anil'),
(12,'Viktor'),
(14,'Sherry'),
(15,'Juan'),
(48,'Susan'),
(50,'Kevin');

declare @EEChange table  (EENo int, Action_type char, Action_date date);
insert @EEChange values 
(6,'H','5/1/1998'),
(6,'T','7/26/2010'),
(12,'H','5/1/1998'),
(12,'R','4/16/2012'),
(14,'H','5/1/1998'),
(14,'R','9/13/2006'),
(14,'T','9/19/2008'),
(15,'H','3/23/1998'),
(48,'H','7/1/1998'),
(48,'R','10/21/2008'),
(48,'T','1/3/2009'),
(50,'H','7/2/1998'),
(50,'R','7/16/2010'),
(50,'T','5/1/2012'),
(50,'R','12/1/2013'),
(50,'T','2/15/2015');
;with CTE AS (
SELECT 
LTRIM(employees.EE) as [EE No],employees.Name,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY employees.EE ORDER BY EEChange.action_date) AS [Seq],
EEChange.action_type,
CASE WHEN EEChange.action_type = 'H' OR EEChange.action_type = 'R' THEN
    EEChange.action_date
    END AS [Effective Date],
CASE WHEN EEChange.action_type = 'T' THEN
    EEChange.action_date
    END AS [Term Date]
FROM @employees employees
LEFT OUTER JOIN @EEChange EEchange ON employees.EE = EEChange.EEno
)

select [EE No],Name,MIN([Effective Date])[Effective Date],MIN([Term Date])[Term Date] from CTE 
GROUP BY [EE No],Name
UNION 
select [EE No],Name,MAX([Effective Date])[Effective Date],MAX([Term Date])[Term Date] from CTE 
where Seq > 3
group by [EE No],Name
```